# Laravel Auth::hasUser always false in Global Scope

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code in my model:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(new CompanyScope);
}
```

Here is my `CompanyScope`:

```
class CompanyScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        \Log::info('apply');

        if (Auth::hasUser()) {
            \Log::info('auth');

            $builder->where($model->getTable() . '.company_id', company()->id);
        }
    }
}
```

In my log, I only see `apply`, I do not see `auth`, nor is the scope being applied.

Why?

Comment: I faced the same problem. `AppServiceProvider` also can't handle Auth without a `MiddleWare`

Comment: Trying changing `Auth::hasUser()` to `Auth::check()`.

Answer (score -1):

I just tested what you have here except I've used `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log` rather than `\Log` and it seems it works fine as long as you are actually testing it with the authenticated user:

**app/User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Scopes\CompanyScope;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new CompanyScope);
    }
}
```

**app/Scopes/CompanyScope.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

class CompanyScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        Log::info('apply');

        if (Auth::hasUser()) {
            Log::info('auth');

            $builder->where($model->getTable() . '.company_id', company()->id);
        }
    }
}
```

In my controller I just fetch the user with id 1:

```
/**
* Get landing view.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
*/
public function index(): JsonResponse
{
    $user = User::find(1);

    return new JsonResponse([
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

and the corresponding test:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function global_scope()
{
    $this->actingAs($user = factory(User::class)->create(['id' => 1]));

    $this->assertTrue($user->exists);
    $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);

    $response = $this->get(route('home'));

    $response->assertExactJson([
        'user' => $user->toArray()
    ]);
}
```

After running the test, my log file contains:

```
[2020-02-16 14:18:59] testing.INFO: apply  
[2020-02-16 14:18:59] testing.INFO: auth
```

If you try the same without logging the user in, then only `apply` will be logged.